# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined using Laravel and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following select box:

```
 <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="numero_projet" id="numero_projet">
    <option label="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
    @foreach($projets as $projet)
      <option data-id="{{$projet->id_projet}}" value="{{$projet->id_projet}}">{{$projet->numero_projet}}</option>
    @endforeach
   </select>
```

And the following ajax code to get data :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#numero_projet').change(function(){

            var id_projet = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");

            console.log(id_projet);

        $.ajaxSetup({

            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 
        $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }

          });
        
        $.ajax({
                  
            url:"getProjet/"+id_projet,
            type:"GET",
             success:function(html){

            var content = html.content;
   
        $("div.name_casting").append(content.id_casting);
    
        }
            
    })
        })

        })
</script>
```

And the following controller:

```
 public function getProjet()

    {

    if(request()->ajax())
        {
           $id_projet = request('numero_projet');

          $projets_casting = Projet_Casting::where('id_projet',$id_projet)->get();

            return response()->json(['projets_casting' => $projets_casting]);
          
        }
    }
```

And I have the following view where I should display the data that I get from controller:

```
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Select from Library</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                @foreach($projets_casting as $projet_casting)
                    <div class="modal-body scroll pt-0 pb-0 mt-4 mb-4">
                        <div class="accordion" id="accordion">
                            <div class="mb-2">
                                <button class="btn btn-link p-0 folder-button-collapse" data-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                    <span class="icon-container">
                                        <i class="simple-icon-arrow-down"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="folder-name">Castings</span>
                                </button>
                                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
                                    <div class="list disable-text-selection">
                                        <div class="row">
                                       
                                            <div class="col-6 mb-1 sfl-item-container casting"
                                                data-preview-path="img/products/chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg"
                                                data-path="img/products/chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg"
                                                data-label="chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg">
                                                <div class="card d-flex mb-2 p-0 media-thumb-container">
                                                    <div class="d-flex align-self-stretch">
                                                        <img src="img/products/chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg" alt="uploaded image"
                                                            class="list-media-thumbnail responsive border-0" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 min-width-zero">
                                                        <div
                                                            class="card-body pr-1 pt-2 pb-2 align-self-center d-flex min-width-zero">
                                                            <div class="w-100">
                                                                <p class="truncate mb-0">{{$projet_casting->id_casting}}</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div
                                                            class="custom-control custom-checkbox pl-1 pr-1 align-self-center">
                                                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                                                                <span class="custom-control-label"></span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                         

                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 @endforeach    
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary sfl-submit">Selectionner</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

It should display in this div the `id_casting` of each projects

```
<div class="w-100 name_casting">
 <p class="truncate mb-0">ok</p>
</div>
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id_casting' of undefined

What is wrong with my code?

**Update**

I have the following HTML in my view:

```
 <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
                                    <div class="list disable-text-selection">
                                        <div class="row">
                                       
                                            <div class="col-6 mb-1 sfl-item-container casting"
                                                data-preview-path="img/products/chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg"
                                                data-path="img/products/chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg"
                                                data-label="chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg">
                                                <div class="card d-flex mb-2 p-0 media-thumb-container casting2">
                                                    <div class="d-flex align-self-stretch">
                                                        <img src="img/products/chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg" alt="uploaded image"
                                                            class="list-media-thumbnail responsive border-0" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 min-width-zero">
                                                        <div
                                                            class="card-body pr-1 pt-2 pb-2 align-self-center d-flex min-width-zero">
                                                            <div class="w-100 castings">
                                                                <p class="truncate mb-0">OK</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div
                                                            class="custom-control custom-checkbox pl-1 pr-1 align-self-center">
                                                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                                                                <span class="custom-control-label"></span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                         

                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

And I'm trying the following script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#numero_projet').change(function(){

            var id_projet = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");

            console.log(id_projet);

        $.ajaxSetup({

            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 
        $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }

          });
        
        $.ajax({
                  
            url:"getProjet/"+id_projet,
            type:"GET",
             dataType:"json",
             success:function(json){
                     renderTemplate(json)
             }
    });

        function renderTemplate(json) {
        var content = ` <div">
                   <p class="truncate mb-0">${json.id_casting}</p>
                    </div>`;

    $("div.name_casting").append(content);
}
        })

        })

</script>
```

But I have nothing. I have always `OK` and I have no error!

**UPDATE2**

Now I can get the data that I want, but I get multiple rows in the same time so I should having multiple divs in my HTML.

I'm getting the following result:

[image]

While I shoult get the 18 in a div and 19 in other div and not in the same place.

Comment: The error is because `html.content` is empty. You need to check the response of the AJAX call to see what the actual response is, and debug the problem from there if it's not what you expect it to be

Comment: The response is still the `id_casting` JSON not HTML. If you want to do it like @professor suggested in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68374738/7451109) today, you need to `return view('your-view', ['projets_casting' => $projets_casting]);`

Comment: @shaedrich n thank you for your help , but this ino a good ide to use this approach

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Analogous to [@professor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7433024/professor)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68374818/7451109):

1. **Use the JSON** *(recommended)*
   The Controller doesn't have to be modified
   In your blade/JavaScript, change the following:

```
$.ajax({                  
    url:"getProjet/"+id_projet,
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(json){
        renderTemplate(json)
    }        
});

function renderTemplate(json) {
    var content = `<div>
        ${json.castings.map((casting) => casting.id_projet)}
    </div>`;

    $("div.name_casting").append(content);
}
```

2. **Use the HTML**
   The blade view and JavaScript
   In your controller, change the following:

```
public function getProjet()
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        $id_projet = request('numero_projet');

        $projets_casting = Projet_Casting::where('id_projet',$id_projet)->get();

        return view('your-view', ['projets_casting' => $projets_casting]);          
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `console.log(json)` output?

Comment: `{castings: Array(0)}
castings: []
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Okay, for some reason, the key seems to be `castings`  then. Does changing the key in your JavaScript code fix your issue?

Comment: that means instead of json I shoul put castings ?

Comment: `<p class="truncate mb-0">${json.castings}</p>`. But keep in mind, that `castings` is an array which is a [complex data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#data_and_structure_types) which shouldn't be outputted directly in the blade template (e.g. loop over it).

Comment: but the problem is ho can I get the value of a specific column from castings ?

Comment: I updated my question. The column, I used is of course just an example.

Comment: thank you for your help and ansxer , please check my update 2

Comment: Please add your whole template HTML as well that reflects the image you added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234858/discussion-between-user14053977-and-shaedrich).

Comment: Feel free to let us know if you were able to implement a solution if you like.